# Zingchart doesn't get rendered. (Angular 16)

Tags: angular, zingchart

I am trying to get a chart shown but the page stays clear.

Did so far:
`npm i zingchart --save`
`npm i zingchart-angular --legacy-peer-deps`

app.component.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>

  <div id="myChart"></div>

  <script>
    let chartData = {
      type: 'pareto',
      series: [
        {
          values: [
            4642,
            4345,
            2350,
            1251
          ]
        }
      ]
    };

    // Render Method[3]
    zingchart.render({ 
      id: 'myChart',
      data: chartData,
      height: 400,
      width: '100%'
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

"@angular/core": "^16.1.0"
"zingchart": "^2.9.11-1"
"zingchart-angular": "^1.0.17"

Tried the actual Edge and Chromium browsers.

Any help is very appreciated.
Sascha

Comment: https://github.com/zingchart/zingchart-angular/issues/52

Comment: zingchart-angular wrapper is now compatible with Angular 16. Please try running your demo again.